# What is the most efficient way to perform CRUD operations to millions of documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and currently doing a project where MongoDB is my primary Database Management System. I am using Mongoose as the Object Data Modeling. Suppose, I have two collections called **products** and **features**. And each product may have multiple features that is a one-to-many relationship.

```
// products schema
const products = mongoose.Schema({
  id: Number,
  name: String,
  description: String,
  category: String,
  price: Number,
}, {
  strict: false,
});
// features schema
const features = mongoose.Schema({
  id: Number,
  product_id: Number,
  feature: String,
  value: String,
}, {
  strict: false,
});
```

I have imported documents/records for both of the collections from external **.csv** files and the number of records for both collections are more than 3 million. My client-side application requires data about a particular product with all the features in it like below:

```
{
  productId: 3,
  name: 'Denim Jeans',
  description: '',
  category: 'Cloth',
  price: 40.00,
  features: [
     {
    feature: 'Material',
    value: 'Cotton',
    },
    {
    feature: 'color',
    value: 'blue',
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

Each product will not have more than 5-6 features. So, what I wanted to do is to embed the features document as a subdocument in the products document like the response above. So, I wrote a piece of code like this. It's not the exact same code as I deleted it from my code when it was not working but the logic is the same.

```
db.products.find({}, (err, product) => {
  // product -> array of all documents from products collection 
    // for each product, I am trying to find the corresponding feature from
    // the features collections and embed it to each product document  
    product.forEach(item => {
      db.features.find({product_id: item.id}, (err, feature) => {
         // feature -> array of all the features of a product
         // embed the feature array to each individual product item
         item.features = feature;
     })
    
  })
})
```

Now, the issue is when I run the above piece of code, I got errors like **OutOfMemory** as it is trying to read from millions of records and my memory is not capable of holding all of this. My question is what is the best way to retrieve all the products and for each individual product write a query to get its corresponding features and embed it inside each product document.

I have a couple of ideas. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. Instead of storing all the products and their features in memory, I want to store them on the disk and update the individual product using the Bulk API of MongoDB. But in that case, how to achieve this and I am concerned about the performance. What is the best practice to follow in this case? Or, should I keep them in a separate collection and from the application server make two queries and package the response there? Or, should I use any kind of aggregation pipeline on the database level? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a `$lookup`aggregation stage for doing a 'join' on two related collections. Ideally, since product and its features are related data they need to be within the same collection.

Comment: @prasad_ Yeah, that's what I wanted to do, keeping them in the same document and avoiding any `$lookup` . Do you have anything on your mind?

Comment: Not only you are loading all the products and features in memory, you're doing it in a "N+1 query" fashion (really slow). If you're looking to mutate your data to embed features within products, I'd do it in batches: fetch 1000 products, fetch all features for those 1000 products, correlate them in the app, prepare and execute a bulk update.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for the suggestion. So, just to be sure I understood it correctly, you are saying instead of making an individual query for every product and its features, In One single query using Batch/Bulk API ,I will first grab 1000 or 10000 products, grab their features and prepare them together until I finish processing all the products. so, the number of the total batch queries will be around 2 million / 1000 (if the batch size is 1000). Is it so?

Comment: In such case, see this: [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: @AshequlHaque: yep, that sounds about right.